# Why does CreateEnvironmentBlock on a WOW64 process give me PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64

Tags: windows, winapi, environment-variables

If I try to create an environment block from within a 32 bit process (on a 64 bit OS) using CreateEnvironmentBlock() the environment block I get seems to be mostly correct but it has a few differences from one that gets created automatically by CreateProcess.  Most notably PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE is usually x86 on 32 bit processes but the one from CreateEnvironmentBlock is amd64.

```
BOOL bResult = FALSE;
LPWSTR wszEnvBlock = NULL;
HANDLE tokenHandle;

OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &tokenHandle);

bResult = ::CreateEnvironmentBlock((LPVOID*)&wszEnvBlock, tokenHandle, TRUE);

LPWSTR wszCurrentItem = wszEnvBlock;
LPWSTR wszEqualsSign = NULL;
LPWSTR wszCurrentItemInuse = NULL;

ATL::CStringW wstrCurrentName;
ATL::CStringW wstrCurrentValue;

while (L'\0' != *wszCurrentItem)
{
    // Find the equals and temporarily set it to NULL
    wszCurrentItemInuse = wszCurrentItem;
    wszEqualsSign = wcschr(wszCurrentItem, L'=');
    *wszEqualsSign = L'\0';

    // Copy the Name and then set the equals back as it was
    wstrCurrentName = wszCurrentItem;
    *wszEqualsSign = L'=';

    // Move the current item to the next character after the equals sign,
    // Then copy the Value
    wszCurrentItem = ++wszEqualsSign;
    wstrCurrentValue = wszCurrentItem;

    // Move the current item to the next character after the terminating NULL character.
    wszCurrentItem = wcschr(wszCurrentItem, L'\0');
    wszCurrentItem++;

    // Insert the two read strings into the map
    wprintf(L"%s:%s\n", wstrCurrentName, wstrCurrentValue);
}

bResult = DestroyEnvironmentBlock((LPVOID)wszEnvBlock);
```

Produces the following output:

> ADMSOURCE:\ddwds02\platform8\DesktopPersonalisation\Win7\GO\Source\adm
>   ALLUSERSPROFILE:C:\ProgramData APPDATA:C:\Users\bens\AppData\Roaming
>   asl.log:Destination=file AS_WDK6_DIR:C:\WinDDK\6000
>   AS_WDK7_DIR:C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.0 CLASSPATH:.;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip CommonProgramFiles:C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files CommonProgramFiles(x86):C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files CommonProgramW6432:C:\Program Files\Common Files
>   COMPUTERNAME:APWADEV03 ComSpec:C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
>   CYGWIN:nodosfilewarning DEFAULT_CA_NR:CA100 DEVELOPMENT:c:\development
>   DEVLIBS:C:\development\libs FP_NO_HOST_CHECK:NO HOME:c:\users\bens
>   HOMEDRIVE:C: HOMEPATH:\Users\bens INCLUDE:C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\SDK\v1.1\includ e\
>   LIB:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET
>   2003\SDK\v1.1\Lib\ LOCALAPPDATA:C:\Users\bens\AppData\Local
>   LOCALHOMESHARE:C:\Users\bens LOGONSERVER:\APWADC01
>   NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS:2 OS:Windows_NT
>   PATHEXT:.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
>   PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:AMD64 PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432:AMD64
>   PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER:Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10,
>   GenuineIntel PROCESSOR_LEVEL:6 PROCESSOR_REVISION:170a
>   ProgramData:C:\ProgramData ProgramFiles:C:\Program Files (x86)
>   ProgramFiles(x86):C:\Program Files (x86) ProgramW6432:C:\Program Files
>   PSModulePath:C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
>   PUBLIC:C:\Users\Public PVC_DDK_DIR:C:\WinDDK\6000 QTJAVA:C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip SESSIONNAME:Console
>   SP2C_ROOT:C:\Development\SP2C_Win7 SystemDrive:C:
>   SystemRoot:C:\Windows TEMP:C:\Users\bens\AppData\Local\Temp
>   TMP:C:\Users\bens\AppData\Local\Temp USERPROFILE:C:\Users\bens
>   VisualStudioDir:C:\Users\bens\Documents\Visual Studio 2010
>   VS100COMNTOOLS:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\Tools \ VS71COMNTOOLS:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio .NET 2003\Common7\T ools\ VS80COMNTOOLS:C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\
>   VS90COMNTOOLS:c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\Tools\ windir:C:\Windows WIX:C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3\ WTTBIN:C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Driver Test Manager\Controller\
>   _NT_SYMBOL_PATH:srv*c:\
>   websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;sr v*c:\pdbs
>   PATH:C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Syst
>   em32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\GTK 2-Runtime\bin;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom
>   802.11\Driver;C:\Program Files\ Microsoft Driver Test
>   Manager\Controller\;C:\Program Files (x86)\FogBugz\FogBugz  Command
>   Line Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\ ;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsof t SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools \Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\B inn\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\cygwinx\b
>   in;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86 )\Common Files\Teleca Shared;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Progr am Files
>   (x86)\AMD\CodeAnalyst\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Nmap;c:\Users\bens\scr ipts\win;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 10.0\;C:\Program Files ( x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\bin;

So is CreateEnvironmentBlock just broken on wow64?  Also, the system environment seems to be defined in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment

How come there's no wow64 equivalent of this?

Comment: Hmm, looks like I'm not the first to see this.  Maybe it's a bug? http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Platform-SDK-Shell/32819766/problems-with-createnvironmentblock-in-64bit-vista.aspx

Comment: `The bug is at CreateEnviromentBlock,
however, the product team currently does not have the plan to fix it in Vista though the fix has been checked into the next version of Windows.`... did you try this on Win7?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Win 7, bug still seems to be there.

Comment: The bug at the link you post is not the same as what you report here

Comment: No, it's not exactly the same, that's true.  It does however look like CreateEnvironmentBlock is still fairly broken.

Comment: @Benj In that call to CreateEnvironmentBlock FALSE was passed to inherit handles and that seemed to be the key to the bug.

Comment: Have you checked what happens to it when you actually start a 32-bit process with this environment?

Comment: David, in my case, passing TRUE or FALSE both result in the same wrong behavior.

Comment: @Benj So what? That bug is still different bug since the bug linked to is predicated on FALSE being passed.

Comment: @David Yeh, that's why I originally agreed with you that it's not exactly the same bug.

Comment: @Hans - If you call CreateProcess to create a 32 bit process with the environment from CreateEnvironmentBlock and the look at it in process explorer it still has the wrong environment (I.e. PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64) if you pass NULL for the environment then you get PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86.  So basically you have to frig the environment yourself if you want this to work.

Comment: Hmm, result, looks like MS are going to fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with CreateEnvironmentBlock(), MS are aware of the issue and have promised to fix it in some unspecified future release.

Comment: Is it just me or is this bug still not fixed?